# In Rails, how does validates_length_of handle multibyte characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Ruby on Rails can validate user input using `validates_length_of` method. How does this method handle multibyte characters?

**Example**

```
validates_length_of :title, :within => 0..10
```

`"abcde"` will pass the validation and `"12345678901"` will not. How about `"一二三四五六"`? Will it pass the validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should handle it correctly if you want to count the number of characters, it handles it as a string, not as bytes.

Further information here

http://railspikes.com/2009/7/20/validates_length_of-gotcha